# link_to with has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

i have a list of tags in questions.. now i want to give each tag a link with corresponding questions in each tag
                                                                                                Tags:

```
<%= link_to question.tags.map { |t| t.name  }.join("  "), @tag %> </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code

```
<% question.tags.each do |t| %>
  <%= link_to(t.name, t) + " " %>
<% end %>
```